# How to convert multidimensional array to dataframe using Spark in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

This is my first time using spark or scala so I am a newbie. I have a 2D array, and I need to convert it to a dataframe. The sample data is a joined table that is in the form of rectangle (double), point (a,b) also doubles, and a boolean of whether or not the point lies within the rectangle. My end goal is to return a dataframe with the name of the rectangle, and how many times it appears where ST_contains is true. Since the query returns all the instances where it is true, I simply am trying to sort by rectangle (they are named as doubles) and count each occurrence. I put that in an array and then try to convert it to a dataset. Here is some of my code and what I have tried:

```
// Join two datasets (not my code)
spark.udf.register("ST_Contains",(queryRectangle:String, pointString:String)=>(HotzoneUtils.ST_Contains(queryRectangle, pointString)))
val joinDf = spark.sql("select rectangle._c0 as rectangle, point._c5 as point from rectangle,point where ST_Contains(rectangle._c0,point._c5)")
joinDf.createOrReplaceTempView("joinResult")

// MY CODE
// above join gets a view with rectangle, point, and true. so I need to loop through and count how many for each rectangle
//sort by rectangle asc first
joinDf.orderBy("rectangle")

var a = Array.ofDim[String](1, 2)
for (row <- joinDf.rdd.collect){  
    var count = 1
    var previous_r = -1.0
    
    var r = row.mkString(",").split(",")(0).toDouble
    var p = row.mkString(",").split(",")(1).toDouble
    var c = row.mkString(",").split(",")(2).toDouble
    
    if (previous_r != -1){
        if (previous_r == r){
            //add another to the count
            count = count + 1
        }
        else{
            //stick the result in an array
            a ++= Array(Array(previous_r.toString, count.toString))
        }
    }    
    previous_r = r
}
//create dataframe from array and return it
val df = spark.createDataFrame(a).toDF()
```

But I keep getting this error:

> inferred type arguments [Array[String]] do not conform to method createDataFrame's type parameter bounds [A <: Product]
> val df = spark.createDataFrame(a).toDF()

I also tried it without the .toDf() portion and still no luck. I tried it without the createDataFrame command and just the .toDf but that did not work either.

Comment: Where is your sample data?

Comment: @Lamanus I added a description of the data in my question and added the few lines of code before the code I wrote. The few lines I added show the data I am starting with. It is not my code, but I labeled where mine starts.

Answer (score 0):

A few things here:

1. `createDataFrame` has multiple variations and the one you end up trying is probably:

```scala
    def createDataFrame[A <: Product : TypeTag](data: Seq[A]): DataFrame
```

`Array[String]` is no `Seq[A <: Product]`: `String` is not a `Product`.

The fastest approach I can think of is go into a `Seq` and then a `DataFrame`:

```scala
import spark.implicits._

Array("some string")
  .toSeq
  .toDF
```

or [parallelize the `Array[String]` into a `RDD[String]`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#parallelized-collections) and then [create the `DataFrame`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/sql-programming-guide.html#programmatically-specifying-the-schema).

2. That second `toDF()` has no value, `createDataFrame` already returns a `DataFrame` (if it worked).